# How to define S4 method for taking the opposite of the object?

Tags: r, r-s4

Let's say I have an S4 class called `testClass`.  The contents are irrelevant the purpose of this question but let's make it contain a numeric value.

```
#' An S4 class that stores a list.
#' @export
setClass("testClass", 
                 representation(a="numeric"))
```

I would like to define a method that works like the taking the opposite of an object.  For example:

```
vec <- rnorm(10)
-vec
```

I thought this would be declaring an `Arith` method with the first argument missing.

```
#' @export
setMethod("Arith", c(e1="missing", e2="testClass"),
                    function(e1, e2)
                    {
                        op = .Generic[[1]]
                        switch(op,
                            `-` = return(-e2@a)
                        )
                    }
)
```

However, when I try to apply the method I get the following error:

```
tc <- new("testClass", a=2)
-tc
```

> Error in -tc : invalid argument to unary operator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hah!  After fiddling some more with it I discovered that it is the `e2` argument that needs to be missing.  The following works:

```
#' @export
setMethod("Arith", c(e1="testClass", e2="missing"),
                    function(e1, e2)
                    {
                        op = .Generic[[1]]
                        switch(op,
                            `-` = return(-e1@a)
                        )
                    }
)
```

Comment: Nice demo. Just out of curiosity, where does that `.Generic` come from (i.e. where is its value to be found)?

Comment: ` ?.Generic` produces after some scrolling: `‘.Generic’ is a length-one character vector naming the generic function.`

Comment: Is there any difference if you try `setMethod("-", c(e1="testClass", e2="missing"), function(e1, e2) -e1@a)`?